# what are BTR points in Bter exchange

Tags: bter

what are BTR points in Bter exchange? Can we convert BTR into an alt-coin? If so, is there any fees they charge. How many times can I exercise this option for a particular month?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've read through a few pages and it looks like Bter Points are used to be an incentive for trading.  Bter states that you can only obtain these by trading in CNY, however, I've never traded in CNY and my balance always changes.

I also know that they deduct points from your balance when you withdraw funds, however, reaching 0 Bter Points doesn't seem to stop your ability to withdraw.  It just diminishes your point balance.  After a bit of experimentation today, I did find a use for them and I'm glad that I did "poke" around the site.

From the menu, click on Bonus->My Dividend.  Apparently Bter pays out site dividends if you request them.  From the My Dividend site, you can request a dividend payment in CNY or BTQ.  I'm not fully sure what BTQ is, so I clicked CNY.  When you request CNY, Bter will deduct half of your points and payout a certain rate of points-to-CNY.

After obtaining about 9 CNY, I bought some BTC and used them to purchase another currency.  So... you can use your points to manually cash out a little Chinese fiat.  It's not much but it's nice if you know it's there.